# Remove Activities from reshosted designer surface

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-rehosting

I have a rehosted designer in my application that is all working ok with my custom activities. When the user is designing their workflows, they will drag certain activities on to the designer surface just like normal. However, after the user selects certain values from a drop down box (not in the designer), I want to remove certain activities from the design surface so they can not be saved and executed.

I have tried so many different ways for doing this, using the WorkflowInspectionServices object to navigate the ModelItemTree, grabbing the parent Sequence activity and removing the custom ones from it's Activities collection but I just can't seem to make it work.

Has anyone out there actually managed to successfully remove an activity from a rehosted designer surface in code (not just right clicking it and choosing Delete!!).

To be clear...this is not when the workflow is being executed, but when it's being designed in a rehosted designer.

Comment: I'm going to bet you don't remove children from the ModelItem but the Activity tree that the ModelItem wraps.  I.e., you do a "GetCurrentValue", cast the return to your Activity type, then remove the children that way.  That won't work, as the ModelItem representation of the Activity tree will get out of sync.  You'll have to remove children by getting the ModelItem for the property that holds the children, then clear that out.

Comment: Hi Will. Thanks for that.  You're right, that is exactly what I'm doing. I know exactly where you're coming from, but just not sure how to actually do it. Does that mean I can get a ModelItem from the parent activity (Sequence?) of the ones I need to clear? Sorry, quite new to all this...

Comment: Lemme see if I can work up a touch of code and I'll answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to bet you don't remove children from the ModelItem but the Activity tree that the ModelItem wraps. I.e., you do a "GetCurrentValue", cast the return to your Activity type, then remove the children that way. That won't work, [as the ModelItem representation of the Activity tree will get out of sync.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwinkle/archive/2009/10/28/deep-dive-into-the-designer-data-model-modelitem-and-modelproperty.aspx) You'll have to remove children by getting the ModelItem for the property that holds the children, then clear that out.

For example, given the following activity

```
[Designer(typeof(NativeActivity1Designer))]
public sealed class NativeActivity1 : NativeActivity, IActivityTemplateFactory
{
    public Activity Child { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context) { }

    Activity IActivityTemplateFactory.Create(System.Windows.DependencyObject target)
    {
        return new NativeActivity1
        {
            Child = new Sequence()
        };
    }
}
```

and the following designer (ActivityDesigner node removed for brevity)

```
<StackPanel>
    <sap:WorkflowItemPresenter
        MinHeight="100"
        HintText="Drop it here"
        Item="{Binding ModelItem.Child}" />
    <Button
        Content="Remove"
        Click="Button_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

you can use the code in `Button_Click` to remove the child from the workflow in the designer.

```
public partial class NativeActivity1Designer
{
    public NativeActivity1Designer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ModelProperty child = ModelItem.Properties["Child"];
        child.SetValue(null);
    }
}
```